# Java / unpack the string /

Tags: java

How I can unpack the string? The input is a string of the form with letters, numbers and symbols, the output is a string containing repeated substrings.

example:
Input: 2[qwe]4[qw]e
Output: qweqweqwqwqwqwe

one repetition may contain another.
example: 2[3[q]w] = qqqwqqqw

Unfortunately, I can only divide into components

=======================================================================

```
StringBuilder alphabetsBuilder = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder numbersBuilder = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder symbolsBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
    char ch = string.charAt(i);
    int ch2 = string.charAt(i);
    
    if (Character.isAlphabetic(ch)) {
        alphabetsBuilder.append(ch);
    } else if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
        numbersBuilder.append(ch2);
        } else {
        symbolsBuilder.append(ch);
    }
}
System.out.println("Alphabets in string: " + alphabetsBuilder.toString());
System.out.println("Numbers in String: " + numbersBuilder.toString());
System.out.println("Symbols in String: " + symbolsBuilder.toString());
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: As a hint here: You're going to need to write an expression _parser_ to solve this problem.  Start researching on that, to point yourself in the right direction.

Comment: The code in the question doesn't appear to be related to the question.  Please show us your actual attempt at solving the problem.  Also, please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 3):

There are many different approaches to this problem. You can write a parser which will recursively process the string, use a regular expression substitution in a loop, etc. One of the possibilities is an iterative unrolling of the expression. On each step you try to find the innermost pair of brackets and replace it with the corresponding substring repeated multiple times. For example, consider the following input string:

```
2[3[q]w]e3[q]
```

First you use an `indexOf(']')` to locate the first closing bracket in the string, it will be found at position 5 (remember, the positions in the string start with 0):

```
2[3[q]w]e3[q]
     ^
     |
 position 5
```

Then you take the substring preceding this position:

```
2[3[q]
```

And find the last opening bracket here with `lastIndexOf('[')`, it will find the bracket at position 3:

```
2[3[q]
   ^
   |
  position 3
```

Now you'll need to extract the number in front of this opening bracket, you'll get number of repetitions: '3'. So, now you take all this information: the number of repetitions and the substring between the brackets to produce the replacement:

```
3[q] => qqq
```

Now you make this replacement in the original string:

```
2[3[q]w]e3[q] => 2[qqqw]e3[q]
```

And now you repeat the whole process from the start.

You search for the first closing bracket, find it here:

```
2[qqqw]e3[q]
      ^
```

Find the last opening bracket in the preceding substring:

```
2[qqqw]
 ^
```

Extract the number of repetitions: 2, and make a replacement

```
2[qqqw] => qqqwqqqw
```

Substitute in the original string:

```
2[qqqw]e3[q] => qqqwqqqwe3[q]
```

Again repeat the whole process, this will lead to the replacement

```
qqqwqqqwe3[q] => qqqwqqqweqqq
```

At this point you'll try to repeat the whole process, but won't find any closing bracket, so you stop and print the result:

```
qqqwqqqweqqq
```

Comment: Alex, thank you for the detailed idea of the solution

Comment: You are welcome, if you'll find some problems in making it working - feel free to ask, show your effort, what is not working, etc.

Comment: Don't forget to take care of cases like unmatched brackets, and brackets which are not preceded by a number.